# React server side render - How to get the build number from WebPack to reference bundle.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

In this simple react server render example:

```
app.use('/index.html', (req, res) => {
const initialState = parseInt(req.query['start-from'] || '0')
const store = createStore(initialState)
const Root = rootFactory(store)
res.send(`
<html><body>
<div id="root">${ReactDomServer.renderToString(<Root/>)}</div>
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = 
${JSON.stringify(store.getState())}</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body></html>`)
```

Looking at the line in which I do: **src="main.js"**. But in the production, the webpack build number is added to the file name like so **“main.f44afe24.js”**
How can plant the correct build number here in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read the revisioned file name from the Webpack stats which can be written to disk at compile time with a plugin such as [this](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/webpack-stats-plugin) or [this](https://github.com/unindented/stats-webpack-plugin).

Official documentation can be found under [long term caching](http://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html)